# Sass+Compass+Susy in Divshot

Tags: susy-compass, divshot

I'm looking for adequate tool to help with responsive design and, so far, Divshot looks as the best one.

Considering that I plan to use Sass+Compass with [Susy](http://susy.oddbird.net/) grid, I wonder if it's possible to use it in Divshot?

As far as I can see, only {Bootstrap, Foundation, Ratchet} are supported, but I'm asking seeing the following quote:

> Here at Divshot we’re huge fans of Sass, a powerful CSS3 preprocessor with attitude. To quickly build our new landing page I took advantage of some nifty mixins I collected from around the web in addition to the myriad of mixins available in Compass.

in [this](http://blog.divshot.com/post/29552945105/useful-sass-mixins-for-responsive-design-font-sizing) post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment Divshot supports Compass but not Susy. You can include Compass in your custom stylesheet like you normally would:

```
@import "compass"
```

Your CSS is sent over to Alloy, our web API for CSS preprocessors. You can take a look at the gems we're using here: https://github.com/divshot/alloy/blob/master/Gemfile. We'll consider adding Susy in the near future!

Comment: Thanks a lot. Having Susy will be great!! Looking forward to it.

Comment: Forgot to ask how to organize custom stylesheets spread in several files, having folder to import images etc., iow. is it possible to have compass's config.rb and set paths for css/scss/imgs/js?

Comment: Custom files and folders aren't available just yet but I promise you that it's arriving very soon! We haven't considered config.rb support in Alloy. I'll discuss with the team.

Comment: Please add it - it would greatly enhance Divshot's usability for more power-users.